# Ruby - elegantly call a method on the elements of two arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am comparing arrays of objects and I have a method that determines whether or not two elements are equivalent. I want to to call this method on each pair of elements from both arrays, is there an elegant way of doing this to find a truth value (i.e true if all elements in each array were equivalent, false otherwise)

this is what I have currently:

```
c = false
self.children.zip(other.children).each do |s,o| 
  c = s.equiv o  # I need a good way to store this result
  break if not c
end
```

I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
c = self.children.zip(other.children).each{|s,o| s.equiv o}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have [Enumerable#all?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F)

```
c = self.children.zip(other.children).all? {|s,o| s.equiv o}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know that all? existed

Comment: See the OP's comment to jmdeldin's answer for why `==` cannot be used.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen..you might not have found it in standard `Array` documentation of Ruby, beacuse it comes in `Enumerable` mixin which is included in Array, Hash, Range etc. It adds a number of useful methods. Checkout the link that I have posted to know these methods.

Comment: @sawa..got it. will edit the post. didnt realize that from reading OP's question first time.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `all?`

```
c = self.children.zip(other.children).all?{|s,o| s.equiv o}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know that all? existed.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is to just define `==` on your objects. Then you can use `Array#==` to do your work because it already does an all-pairs comparison.

Here's a simple example:

```
class Widget
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def ==(other)
    @name == other.name
  end
end

if $0 == __FILE__
  require 'minitest/autorun'

  describe 'widget arrays' do
    let(:some_widgets) { %w(foo bar baz).map { |name| Widget.new(name) } }
    let(:diff_widgets) { %w(bar baz spam).map { |name| Widget.new(name) } }

    it 'returns true if the widget arrays are the same' do
      (some_widgets == some_widgets).must_equal true
    end

    it 'returns false if the widget arrays are different' do
      (some_widgets == diff_widgets).must_equal false
    end
  end
end
```

You just call `some_widgets == my_other_widgets` to compare each element.

Comment: The problem with redifining `==` is I wont be able to tell objects apart. I defined `equiv` instead because for my task, I still need to be able to differentiate between references to the same objects and objects with the same values. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: When you redefine `==` (or any of the other equality methods), you **can** tell objects apart. In this example, if you need to determine whether objects are the same reference or not, use `Object#eql?` through `Array#eql?` (e.g., `[Widget.new('foo')].eql? [Widget.new('foo')] #=> false`).

Comment: @jmeldin I see what you are saying, but I don't want to override `==`, I want it to stay the same, which is what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you replace `each` by `map`, `c` will be the array you're looking for. I can't be 100% sure, because I can't test right away, and I know there is some issues with `zip`.